# Bounce processor scheduled job is working but not flagging emails as bounced

Tags: civimail, bounce

We've had a bounce processor set up (and working) for about 2 years. Recently, I'd guess the last two months I'm not exactly sure when this started, it has not been fully working.

I can see the bounced messages arrive in the bounce email account. After the Bounce fetcher runs (we have it set to run hourly) it moves the emails to the processed folder. What it does not do is then mark the emails on the contact records as bounced.

The scheduled job log shows no errors.

```
Full message: 
Finished execution of Bounces fetcher with result: Success (1)
```

We are in Drupal 7, CiviCRM 5.27.7.

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm not sure where to poke around next to find out where the breakdown might be.

Comment: Are the bounces showing up in the mailing report? Could it be that they just aren't being put on hold because they are the kind of bounces that need 3 tries before being recorded as on hold? In my experience the categorization is pretty fuzzy of the types of bounces.

Comment: They are also not showing up in the mailing report. Thank you, I didn't realize that there were types of bounces that needed three tries before recording on hold but I did just find more info in the documentation (https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/#bounce-handling). Some of the bounces I think would meet the permanent failure, threshold of 1, criteria - like user does not exist, invalid recipient, no such user etc. Either way soft or permanent failure, shouldn't they report to the mailings report?

Comment: They should. There is a known issue with the bounces that they should up in the advanced search you click to from the report when they don't show in the main mailing report itself until some hours later because of a time zone bug, but that doesn't sound like your issue. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable than me can help.